# Second camera for UI in GoogleVR Unity5

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I have a problem on Google VR, as you can see on the screen shot, on the right eye camera, the UI is double. I didn't do anything in the code, I just created another cam for the UI and culling mask is set only to UI, then this is what happened.

What can I do? Please help!  [image]

Comment: without code is hard to help you

Comment: I have inlined the image into your question. However, it is hard for us to help without more information. I suggest you have a look at your XML files, and see if you can find anything there that may be relevant. Then [edit] it into your question. With more information, maybe we can help. Good luck!